# floating content in div and hr

Tags: html, css

The content of `hr` tag flow around floating elements as if it is inline elements (even if it is actually blocks). That's what I need but unfortunately `hr` can't have child elements except two pseudo elements.

Take a look on this demo on JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/P3KEZ/

```html
<div id="right"></div>
<div class="divider"></div>
<hr class="divider" />
```

```css
#right{
    background: #ffaaaa;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    float: right
}

.divider {
    background: #4d9d4d;
    height: 20px;
    border: none;
    position: relative;
}

.divider:after, .divider:before {
    content: " ";
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    background: #a2a2f2;
    top: 0;
}

divider:before {
    left: 0;
}

.divider:after {
    right: 0;
}
```

What I actually want is to get element with content flow around the floating elements (like `hr` do) but also can have at least 3 child elements (like `div` can do).

So question is: how to emulate such behaviour in div? (without `display: flex`)

Comment: why are you using an hr tag? [http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hr.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hr.asp)

Comment: because I want to make divider (as hr do by default but with padding and picture in the middle [margin will not work right with floating content, so I need that 2 pseudo-elements using like paddings])

Comment: hr has layout triggered where div doesn't. http://jsfiddle.net/P3KEZ/3/ trigger layout on div and see it happening too kill layout on hr : http://jsfiddle.net/P3KEZ/4/  do not kill on hr but set width : http://jsfiddle.net/P3KEZ/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I actually want is to get element with content flow around the floating elements (like `hr` do) but also can have at least 3 child elements (like `div` can do).
>
> So question is: how to emulate such behaviour in `div`?

You want to harvest *the power of the mighty `overflow` property … (*thunderclap*)*

```
.divider {
    /* … */
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Normally, a block element is layed out *behind* a floating element, only its inline content floats next to the floated element – but with `overflow:hidden` you can change that, so that a block element like `div` only takes the space that is left beside the floating element. (It does not actually have to be `hidden` – everything besides the default value `visible` will trigger this behavior, so you can use `auto` or `scroll` as well if those suit your actual use-case better.)

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/P3KEZ/1/